# Genitive of demonstrative pronouns in the genitive case

Tags: grammatical-case, demonstrative-pronoun

What is the correct change of the following expression

> alle Fakten, deren Auswirkungen und die ergriffenen Maßnahmen

into the genitive case

> Beschreibung aller Fakten, **der??** Auswirkungen und der ergriffenen Maßnahmen

I thought about *derer* but that is the genitive of the demonstrative plural pronoun *die*. So, what is the genitive of the demonstrative pronoun (*die*) in the genitive case (i.e. *deren*)? Is there a form? Does it simply stay unchanged (i.e. *deren*)? Or, is such an expression not possible at all?

Please consider *dessen*, too.

> der Mann, dessen Haus und Hund

in genitive

> ein Bild des Mannes, **de???** Hauses und Hundes

Comment: Do people, who downvote my question understand at all that I'm asking about the genitive form **of** _dessen/deren_? I'm not asking about how/when to build _dessen/deren_. Is the answer that obvious? I don't think so.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I'm not quite sure what your question is in the first part. Could you provide an English translation for what you intend to say? Possibly even better a complete sentence, context always matters.

Comment: Did you have a look at a [declension table](http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/pronouns/relative-pronouns/) and if so, what remains unclear?

Comment: @BenA. Unfortunately, downloading pertinent questions is not rare here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your confusion now.

What confused me is that you wanted to know the genitive case of `dessen` or `deren` although it is already written in the genitive case. There is no such thing as a "double genitive" version of those. This  may introduce some ambiguity in some cases. But in these example it's quite clear.

> Das ist das Bild des Mannes, dessen Hauses und Hundes

More natural/idiomatic to me is this sentence

> Das ist das Bild des Mannes, seines Hauses und (seines) Hundes.

The same holds true for the first sentence:

> Beschreibung aller Fakten, deren Auswirkungen und der ergriffenen Maßnahmen

You could also rephrase it here, but using *deren* or *dessen* is perfectly fine and correct.

> Beschreibung aller Fakten, ihrer Auswirkungen und der ergriffenen Maßnahmen

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's apparently correct. I've decided to accept the presented similar question because of the contained link to Duden. If this (quasi) authority gives the example _die Ankunft meines Bruders und dessen Verlobter_ I'm satisfied. As a recompensation, I disclose my actual problem. I've been trying to amend (for myself) a grammatical error in the German version of the General Data Protection Regulation (Datenschutz-Grundverordnung). Have a look at "von deren" in art. 33 para. 5. It doesn't match with the text before. "einschließlich" is new. "von deren" was not adjusted.